# How to fire an event only after element is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple tag system.

I am also adding a functionality of removing arrays. However, I ran into a problem. Whenever I launch an event listener to delete the item, I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`.

I know I am getting this error because the element is not visible/created in the DOM. Since, the tags appear only after a button click, how can I launch an event only after tags element is loaded?

Here's the code:

```js
const tagsInput = document.getElementById('tagsField');
const tagsBtn = document.getElementById('getTags');
const ul = document.getElementById('ul');
let tagsRemover = document.getElementsByClassName('removeTag');
let tagsElemnts = document.getElementsByClassName('tags');
let tagsContainer = [];

let getTags = () => {
 if(tagsInput.value) {
  tagsInput.classList.remove('hasError');
  let tags = tagsInput.value.split(",");
  let pure_tags = tags.map((x) => x.trim());
  tagsContainer = [...pure_tags];
 } else {
  tagsInput.classList.add('hasError');
 }
}

let showTags = () => {
 if(tagsContainer.length > 0) {
  tagsContainer.forEach((element) => {
   let container = document.createElement('LI');
   container.innerHTML = '<span class="removeTag">&#10006;&nbsp;</span>'+element;
   container.className = 'tags';
   ul.appendChild(container);
  });
  tagsContainer = [];
  tagsInput.value = '';
 }
}

tagsInput.addEventListener('input', getTags);
tagsBtn.addEventListener('click', showTags);

// I am doing i < 2 just for debug purpose
for(let i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
 tagsRemover[i].onclick = () => {
  tagsElemnts[i].style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```css
label {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
input[type=button] {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #ff4040;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
input[type=text] {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #c2c2c2;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  border-color: #0095ff;
}
.tags {
  list-style: none;
  background: #03A9F4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.removeTag {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hasError {
  border-color: #ff0023 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Get Tags</title>
</head>
<body>
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input type="text" id="tagsField">&nbsp;
 <input type="button" value="Get Tags" id="getTags">
 <br>
 <br>
 <ul id="ul"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check at `tagsRemover[i]` and error will be gone.

Current code:

```
tagsRemover[i].onclick = () => {
  tagsElemnts[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Change to:

```
  if (tagsRemover[i]) {
    tagsRemover[i].onclick = () => {
      tagsElemnts[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

Below is working code snippet:

```js
const tagsInput = document.getElementById('tagsField');
const tagsBtn = document.getElementById('getTags');
const ul = document.getElementById('ul');
let tagsRemover = document.getElementsByClassName('removeTag');
let tagsElemnts = document.getElementsByClassName('tags');
let tagsContainer = [];

let getTags = () => {
  if (tagsInput.value) {
    tagsInput.classList.remove('hasError');
    let tags = tagsInput.value.split(",");
    let pure_tags = tags.map((x) => x.trim());
    tagsContainer = [...pure_tags];
  } else {
    tagsInput.classList.add('hasError');
  }
}

let showTags = () => {
  if (tagsContainer.length > 0) {
    tagsContainer.forEach((element) => {
      let container = document.createElement('LI');
      container.innerHTML = '<span class="removeTag">&#10006;&nbsp;</span>' + element;
      container.className = 'tags';
      ul.appendChild(container);
    });
    tagsContainer = [];
    tagsInput.value = '';
  }
}

tagsInput.addEventListener('input', getTags);
tagsBtn.addEventListener('click', showTags);

// I am doing i < 2 just for debug purpose
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
  if (tagsRemover[i]) {
    tagsRemover[i].onclick = () => {
      tagsElemnts[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

input[type=button] {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #ff4040;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

input[type=text] {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #c2c2c2;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border-color: #0095ff;
}

.tags {
  list-style: none;
  background: #03A9F4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.removeTag {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hasError {
  border-color: #ff0023 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Get Tags</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input type="text" id="tagsField">&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Get Tags" id="getTags">
  <br>
  <br>
  <ul id="ul"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, I guess setInterval is only the last hope available as I need to check continuously if the element is present in the DOM! Do you have any other ideas?